# It's about the cocoapods. An error occurred when I install my podfile. It's like the syntax error about ruby

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I try everything that I've searched, like reinstall my cocoapods, update my gem or cocoapads's version, but it doesn't work. The error log is like:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:15:in `initialize': undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:28:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:28:in `from_file'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:434:in `refresh_metadata'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:55:in `refresh_metadata'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:29:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:310:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:310:in `block in source_from_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `source_from_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:324:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:324:in `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:324:in `aggregate_with_repos'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:24:in `aggregate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:58:in `all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in `repo_information'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in `stack'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Show your podfile, ruby version etc. not enough info. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355998/ruby-newbie-undefined-method-with-indifferent-access

Comment: THX, I'll go search some info . And that's my ruby --version
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]

Comment: Should I update it? And my mac has a default version for ruby which is 2.3.0.

Comment: Check if you are in the correct path. Can you show the podfile?

Comment: step 1 to debugging this: does the podfile contain something weird. update your question and post your podfile, as others have asked

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me, finally I find the reason of this problem. That was because I have three different version of Xcode. But I only use the latest version. So when I switch the default version of Xcode, the problem solved.
It's like:
sudo xcode-select --switch [your xcode path].